# How to grant permission for accessing an AWS SQS queue to a specific EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, permissions, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

I want to use an AWS SQS queue, and access it via a PHP script. The PHP script is installed on EC2 instance.

For testing purposes, I am using curl requests on the EC2 instance right now, for example:

```
curl https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/1234567890/Integration_Order_In?Action=ReceiveMessage
```

Without configuring any permissions, the request fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access to the resource https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/123456789/Integration_Order_In is denied.</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestId>d47c06d5-a36b-5cac-aedb-54996975844f</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
```

This is totally understandable: If no access is configured, requests are rejected. A glance into the header unveils the underlying 403 error.

Understandable is also, that everything works well with the following queue policy (Queue -> Permissions -> Edit Policy Document (Advanced)):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "sqspolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Sid1506985964774",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:644393699576:Magento_Integration_Order_In_Tmall_ShippingLabelDownload__tmall",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "12.34.56.78"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The result looks promising:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ReceiveMessageResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><ReceiveMessageResult/><ResponseMetadata><RequestId>788aeac3-de4d-5d4c-85ad-b88f101f164e</RequestId></ResponseMetadata></ReceiveMessageResponse>
```

But this binds the permission to an IP address, while I would prefer to bind it to an instance (ip addresses might change). Unfortunately, my experiments with adding the arn of my instance or its IAM role did not result in any access to the SQS urls.

The scenario seems to be a bit specific. In other scenarios, for example, it might be feasible to add the access permissions to the IAM role of the EC2 instance. This does not work well in my case for several reasons. I really would prefer to use the permissions on queue level.

Any ideas?